# How to convert nested Json in string into Json object in java

Tags: java, json

I am looking for some Java library, which can convert below give String into Json object.

Input: String reading from file.

```
{ "product": "{\"sku\":\"rtwre-rtwe\",\"price\":\"50.90\",\"currency_code\":\"SGD\",\"quantity\":1}", "is_organic": "0", "can_claim": "0", "t": "r", "device": "Phone", "amount_transactions": "0" }
```

Expected output: In some generic Java Json object.

```
{
   "product": {
      "sku": "rtwre-rtwe",
      "price": "50.90",
      "currency_code": "SGD",
      "quantity": 1
   },
   "is_organic": "0",
   "can_claim": "0",
   "t": "r",
   "device": "Phone",
   "amount_transactions": "0"
}
```

Imp points: This is sample code, I have more dynamic json and don't have any Java object corresponding to my json. I can have string json in any key. It's not specific to particular key. I am looking for more generic code.

Here my goal if I read value of key "product" it should return Json instead of String. I want to read $.product.price using JsonPath library. http://jsonpath.com/

Edit1: I don't have much experience with Gson, Jackson and JsonObject libraries, but I tried whatever I could do. If you had handled the same scenario, please help me out.

Comment: did you spend some times on Gson Library ?

Comment: Jackson is better

Comment: I tried both things and not getting the proper way to handle this scenario.  Could you please give me the example? I want to use JsonPath library on that JsonObject. http://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 2):

To resolve it you can use :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myStringValue);
String myJsonStructureAsString = jsonObj.toString();
```

Where JSONObject is org.json.JSONObject form lib json-org.v2017.05.16.jar

Comment: I think this is not working for me. I want JsonObject in which String should return as JsonObject which were valid Json.

Comment: Did you get my problem? I edited the question again.

Comment: Have no experience using libraries dose not mean that you can not handle it, people create librarie to helps as tod do things fast and clean.